# Passing a range of values into Excel Array - Row by Row

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array

Whilst being pretty proficient in Excel, my VBA consists of me balancing books on my knees copying out segments of code - therefore forgive my ignorance

**Background**
I have a the results of a Monte Carlo engine which consists of 10,000 rows and 60 columns. I need to sequence through the rows and record the results (31 outputs) in a separate worksheet. The code I have written works 'adequately' in that it copies the results into the array 'row-by-row'

It essentially consists of a couple of for loops: the first For Loop goes down the 10,000 rows and the second For Loop uses an OFFSET method to sequence through the 31 contiguous cells in the range.

[This is the loop code that works - albeit slowly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVw0X.png)

**How Could I Speed this Up?**
It occurred to me that I could reduce the run time (maybe?) by cutting out the 2nd loop and simply copy the 31 contiguous cells into a single row of the array for each of the 10,000 cycles. This is where I am having problems.

How do I copy a range of 31 contiguous cells in a horizontal axis (named range "OneScenarioResult") into the correct row of the named array ArrayScenarioResults. I can do it for one row but not incorporate it into the loop for the 10,000 runs.

This is what my pitiful attempt at the single loop looks like. It fails on 'subscript out of range'

[My Attempt at a Single Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU3F5.png)

Thank you for looking

Comment: See [VBA arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code - it's much more difficult for folks to suggest changes if they can't copy/paste and then edit it.

Comment: Without seeing the context and what `ScenarioStep`, `ScenarioCount`, `ScenarioOutputs ` means and how "OriginResultsScenario" looks, your code picture does not say anything. There are more elegant/efficient to add rows/columns, but without knowing the context it is not anything to be improved, I think.